# Why do I get undefined for yes/no radio button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax with jQuery and PHP.

When the user submits part of the multipart form, the results are displayed in a new div. There are a few yes/no radio buttons in the form. But instead of showing "yes" or "no" in the results, I get an "undefined." Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

**HTML**

```
<div class="usedYesNo">
  <h5>Question 1</h5>
  <ul class="YesNo">
    <li>
      <input class="option-child" type="radio" name="YesNo1[]" value="Yes" >
      <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="option-child" type="radio" name="YesNo1[]" value="No" >
      <label for="No">No</label>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="usedYesNo">
  <h5>Question 2</h5>
  <ul class="YesNo">
    <li>
      <input class="option-child" type="radio" name="YesNo2[]" value="Yes" >
      <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="option-child" type="radio" name="YesNo2[]" value="No" >
      <label for="No">No</label>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({

    type: "POST",
    data: {

        YesNo1 : $('YesNo1').val(),
        YesNo2 : $('YesNo2').val()

       },
    dataType: 'json',
    url: './includes/ajaxtest3.php',
    error: function() {alert("error!");},                   
    success: $('#output2').html(data.message.join('<br />'));
 //...
```

**PHP**

```
 $return['message'] = array();
 $return['message'][] = 'Answer to first question: ' . $_POST['YesNo1'];
 $return['message'][] = 'Answer to second question: ' . $_POST['YesNo2'];
  echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused; Ken asked this question, but the person haranguing people below is mcgrailm. I ask because I'd love to downvote this question due to mcgrailm's comments, but I'd hate to punish Ken for it. :P

Comment: @Andrew so what your saying is that you want to downvote my comments ? because you don't think they are good comments ?

Comment: They weren't, no, especially the one where you say someone is wrong, then the link you give proves them to be right. Giving the radio buttons IDs is a 110% valid method. Your method is valid too, but that doesn't make the other method less valid.

Answer (score 3):

you need `#` to get elements by id wrapped inside a jQuery obj

```
$('#YesNo1').val(),
$('#YesNo2').val()
```

Comment: that is true but his they don't have ids and since they are radio buttons id would be impractical since you can't have more than one element with the same id

Comment: @mcgrailm: You wouldn't give them the same id's.

Comment: Precisely. So you give them separate IDs. Just like if they were checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still a little confused. Does this mean that each part of a yes/no pair should have a separate id?

Comment: @webbiedave that what i was saying my point was that ids are impractical for radio buttons since they are joined by name

Comment: @ken no there is not need for id's here please see my answer

Comment: My answer is about retrieving elements with jQuery.. if you had and ID on your radio elements it would be easier for you, btw, you need a more complicated selector (see mcgrailm answer) to grab those elements without an ID :).

Answer (score 3):

Your selector

`$('YesNo1')` is saying look for a tag named `<YesNo1>` as in element

Comment: Why is this being downvoted so much? It is technically correct and provides educational information.

Comment: @mcgrailm Yes it is precisely BECAUSE there is no '#'. Because there is no '#', jQuery is looking for a tag named `<YesNo1>`!

Comment: @mcgrailm, yes it is, a selector string with no preceeding '#' or '.' looks for an element name.

Comment: Er.. that confirms what Gavin said. The first one ("foo") is looking for <foo>, which is why the button does nothing. The second one ("#foo") is looking for the element with id="foo", which is why the button works.

Comment: @mcgrailm, I think you misunderstood what eppascarello said. "A tag named `<YesNo1>`" means that is the name of the tag, not the object. `$('span')` looks for a tag named 'span'. `$('#span')` looks for an object named 'span'.

Answer (score 2):

what you want do is get the input by name where it is selected

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({

    type: "POST",
    data: {

        YesNo1 : $('input[name="YesNo1[]"]:checked').val();
        YesNo2 : $('input[name="YesNo2[]"]:checked').val(); 

       },
    dataType: 'json',
    url: './includes/ajaxtest3.php',
    error: function() {alert("error!");},                   
    success: $('#output2').html(data.message.join('<br />'));
 //...
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/6zypt/)

Comment: @ mcgrailm Thank you. For some reason, I am still getting an "undefined" when I use the above solution. Also, should there be semicolons in the code? My javascript is breaking when I use them as you did.

Comment: sorry you dont' need selected fiddle i had selected confused with checked

Comment: This does not work, your demo simply outputs the first value, `yes` in this case. If you change it for the `no` to be checked, it still alerts `yes`: http://jsfiddle.net/6zypt/3/

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the right selector in your calls to jQuery.

Comment: this is true but you should show what the correct selector should be

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your problem is the names of the radio buttons. To simplify things I would using a naming structure like Q1Yes, Q1No, etc or even try to have your questions phrased so that if a radio button is checked it means the user answered yes and leave it unchecked for no. You could have the name of your radio buttons just Question1 and Question2 at that point.

Comment: this is wrong as well name is not the best for this circumstance butt is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've used this is the past with great success.
You don't need to store the value in an array. Make your inputs like this:

```
<input class="option-child" type="radio" name="YesNo1" value="Yes" > 
<input class="option-child" type="radio" name="YesNo1" value="Yes" >
```

Then you can pull the result of the selected value using jquery.

```
var YesNo1 =$("input[name=YesNo1]:checked").val();
```

YesNo1 will then contain the value of the selected option

Answer (score 0):

The selectors you need are:

```
$('input[name="YesNo1[]"]:checked').val(); 
$('input[name="YesNo2[]"]:checked').val();
```